# Set dictionary value to a variable, not the variable's value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
In [1]: a = None
In [2]: b = None
In [3]: A = {'a': a, 'b': b}
In [4]: A
Out[4]: {'a': None, 'b': None}
In [5]: a = 1
In [6]: A
Out[6]: {'a': None, 'b': None}
```

I am trying to assign a reference to a variable to a dictionary value. I don't want to assign the variable's value to the dictionary's value. Is there someway to do this? Basically, I would want the last line to read:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': None}
```

Comment: If you are only concerned about the local variables, try calling `locals()` instead of your variable `A`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest you will get with python in my opinion:

```
class myobj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mystr=""

    @property
    def mystr(self):
        return self.mystr

    @mystr.setter
    def mystr(self, val):
        self.mystr=val

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mystr

a = myobj()
a.mystr = 'a'

names={'a': a}

print names

a.mystr = 'b'

print names
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because integers are immutable in Python. See [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) for details. You can only change the dictionary value as in:

```
A['a'] = 1
```

When you set `a = 1`, you are actually creating a *new a*, which is why it does not reflected to the dictionary. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Types affect almost all aspects of object behavior. Even the importance of object identity is affected in some sense: for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while for mutable objects this is not allowed. E.g., after a = 1; b = 1, a and b may or may not refer to the same object with the value one, depending on the implementation, but after c = []; d = [], c and d are guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty lists. (Note that c = d = [] assigns the same object to both c and d.)

Answer (score 0):

Python has no support for references. Even in functions, all method parameters are pass-by-value. You can pass a mutable data structure into a function and modify the data structure, but what you describe is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

**Let me explain in a little different way. Hope this will be helpful if you are new to python:**

**Let me use a list object(mutable) to get different id for different object.**

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> id(a)
4405572168
>>> A = {'a': a}
>>> id(A['a'])
4405572168
>>>
```

So far we got the same id of the `a and A['a']`.

Now lets bind another object into the name `a`

```
>>>
>>> a = {1: 2}
>>> id(a)
140196067104096
>>> id(A['a'])
4405572168
>>>
```

In the above eg, i bind a new dict object into `a` and check the identity of `a and A['a']` and now they are different as the name `a` is bind to a totally new object.

**Here is another explanation with reference counting:**

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
2
>>> A = {'a': a}
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
3
>>>
>>> a = {1: 2}
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
2
>>>
```

Can you see the decrease in reference counting after we re-bind to a new name, which means its a totally new object bind to `a`. So, you wont' see the changes on A.

Variable assignment in other language is Name binding in python.